# How to mint limited edition tokens in Solana

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I just what to know the anatomy of how the limited edition non-fungible tokens work on Solana.

Say, I have created a 3D Sword and I would like to mint 100 only out of 3D Sword file.

I am a little confused about how it works Solona SPL Token. Following is my idea on the workflow on how to achieve that. Please correct me if I am wrong and let me know the right way to do that.

1. Create a Token using `spl-token create-token --decimals 0` (ex. this creates token with id TOKEN_ADDRESS_0001)
2. Mint the token using `spl-token mint TOKEN_ADDRESS_0001 100 {SOME_OTHER_ADDRESS}` (see **100** tokens i am minting)
3. Then disable further minting of that token using `spl-token authorize TOKEN_ADDRESS_0001 mint --disable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the "tokenomics" and command line calls all perfectly correct!  The next part to consider will be adding metadata to your 3D sword, and that's where NFT solutions like Metaplex aim to simplify the experience.  There are many resources for Metaplex, so the best place to start would be their repo: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex